# ASP Changed ContentPlaceHolder throughout the whole project and now cannot find what i've changed

Tags: asp.net

i'm getting the error:  Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'ContentPlaceHolder1' in the master page .

This is correct, i changed it to ContentPlaceHolderBottom, the thing is why i did this I performed a find and replace on the entire project.  Where the heck is this error coming from is there another place where I have to change it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you choose the right "find in files" option? You might have only told it to search in *.master files instead of *.aspx files.

Anyway, the problem is caused because you've got `<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderId="ContentPlaceHolder1">` in one of your *.aspx files.

If you're not using MVC it should be easy to find the culprit (hint: check the address bar).

Happy hunting.

Comment: I changed it back to that and it still errors and i did entire solution

Comment: Can you paste the entire Yellow Screen of Death message?